# Can I get emails about Q&A in my watched tags?

Tags: support, email, tag-watching

Is there any way to get all questions/answers of my interested tags in my mailbox using SO?

Answer (score 6):

No.

That was easy.

---

Allow me to explain.

Stack Overflow's only built-in email feature is the feature that allows you to receive notifications about a specific question.

You can use an external service that possibly would use an RSS feed to get the same effect.

Comment: To add to this answer, email will never get a larger role in the trilogy because Jeff hates email.

Comment: its not so much that Jeff hates it as its a soul-sucking inefficient community destroying communication method. :p